# Probability of $P((A ∩ B)|(A \cup\ B))$

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics

If given that A and B are independent then what should I do to get the result of
$P((A ∩ B)|(A \cup\ B))$

Progress
[image]

I'm still not sure what to do because the thing I did was to make use of property of set by switching place so that $A ∩ A = A$ and $B \cup B = B$ to make it minimal but in the end it got the result of $ \frac {P(A \cap\ B)} {P(A\cup\ B)} $ and I don't know where to go next.

I have no idea what to do except using property of set at the moment.

Comment: To get the result, you should think about it, try to make some progress and post about your thoughts on the problem. Then we’ll help you to arrive at the solution.

Comment: @insipidintegrator I have tried doing it but still not working ( I will edit in the picture of the process)

Comment: Nothing can be understood from the picture. Use [mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to type in the progress. It is HIGHLY recommended that you learn mathjax for your current and future questions on this site.

Comment: Let me recreate the one from the picture since I have already erased it

Comment: edited the picture and also I will try to use mathjax from now on Sorry about that.

Comment: @insipidintegrator Is it looking better now?

Comment: Is it $\cup$ or $\cap$?

Comment: @peterwhy edited

Comment: And inside your picture attempt? Somehow the $\cup$ that should be in the denominator became a $\cap$.

Comment: @peterwhy maybe I got confused in the formula of independent. Is the reason why I can't do it right is because I do the denominator thing wrong?

Comment: The first $=$ sign in your image is about the definition of conditional probability, not yet about independence.

Comment: Do the one I did in numerator right though?

Comment: The eventual result of $A\cap B$ is fine, but the intermediate step to convert $(A\cap B)\cap (A\cup B) = (A\cap A)\cap (B\cup B)$ doesn't seem to come immediately from laws or identities. The two side are still equal and right.

Comment: Is the goal to represent everything in terms of $P(A)$ and $P(B)$?

Comment: From the Question it said to find the possibility of $(A ∩ B)|(A \cup\ B)$ 

Given A and B are independent which $P(A) = 3P(A^c)$ and $P(B|A) = \frac{1}{2}$

Comment: $P(A) = 3P(A^C)$, then you know the value of $P(A)$. $P(B\mid A) = \frac 12$, then you know the values of $P(B)$ and $P(B\cap A)$. These are important context to be included in the question in order to find the numerical answer.

Comment: So the next thing I need to do is to find P(AUB) which is equal to $P(A)+P(B) - P(A \cap\ B)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you develop you last expression, because $A$ and $B$ are assumed independent,  using $P(A\cup B)=P(A)+P(B)-P(A)P(B)$ and $P(A\cap B)=P(A)P(B)$, you get
$$P(A\cap B|A\cup B)=\dfrac{1}{\frac{1}{P(A)}+\frac{1}{P(B)}-1}\ (\text{if A, B independent})$$